# How to get nearest next 12 letter long word after a particular word in string in php

Tags: php

I have string below
$string = 'To: Invoice No. Billing Date 704319003027 15-06-2019 PAPIYA DUTTA Sales Order No. Sales Order Date PAIKPARA,MURARAI ROAD District: BIRBHUM , NALHATI - 731220';

I want the 12 character long '704319003027' after the particular words 'Invoice Number'

```
$string = 'Invoice Number: Invoice Name: 704319003027 Rahul Sinha 
 Account Information: Some text here';

 $invoice_no = substr($string, strpos($string, 'Invoice Number:') + strlen($matches[0]), 12);
echo $invoice_no;
```

Comment: After the `'Invoice Number'` or the `'Invoice Name'`?

Comment: after Invoice Number.

Comment: But, there is no number after `'Invoice Number'` in your example.`'Invoice Number: Invoice Name: 704319003027 Rahul Sinha  Account Information: Some text here'`

Answer (score 1):

You can use lookbehind of preg to get first number with 12 chars after `Invoice Number`,[Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/ef93ba35ce1023672f7112cbe5c54b0b0cc6e653)

```
if(preg_match("/(?<=Invoice Number).*([0-9]{12})/",$string,$matches)){
    echo var_dump($matches[1]);
}
```

Comment: Good solution :)

Answer (score 0):

## Option 1

```
<?php
$data = "Invoice Number: 704319003027 Invoice Name: 704319003027 Rahul Sinha Account Information: Some text here";

$whatIWant = substr($data, strpos($data, "Number: ") + 8);
$whatIWant2 = substr($whatIWant, 0, 12);

echo $whatIWant2;
```

## Option 2

```
<?php
$data = "Invoice Number: Invoice Name: 704319003027 Rahul Sinha Account Information: Some text here";

$data = explode(' ', $data);

foreach($data as $key => $value) {
   if (intval($value) && strlen($value) == 12) {
     $data = $value;
     break;
   }
}

var_dump($data);
```

Comment: the string that you are using is not correct, the string is like $string = 'Invoice Number: Invoice Name: 704319003027 Rahul Sinha 
 Account Information: Some text here';  We need the number by using 'Invoice Number' only

Answer (score 0):

You could use `preg_match` to extract the number following "Invoice Name":

```
preg_match('/Invoice Name: ([\d]+) /', $string, $matches);
echo $matches[1];
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a regular expression to match the text you want within the string, like so:

```
$string = 'Invoice Number: Invoice Name: 704319003027 Rahul Sinha Account Information: Some text here';
preg_match('@Invoice Name: (\d{12})@',$string,$matches);
if( !empty( $matches ) )echo $matches[1];
```

Comment: I can use Invoice Number here not the Invoice Name ,@Invoice Number instead of @Invoice Name